# Bound from above on covariance matrix of Gaussian-like distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian, gaussian-integral

Assume that $\rho$ is a probability density such that
$$
\rho(x) \propto \exp \left(-\frac{|x|^2}{2} - f(x) \right).
$$
This means
$$
\rho(x) = \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{|x|^2}{2} - f(x) \right)}{\int_{\mathbb R^n} \exp \left(-\frac{|y|^2}{2} - f(y) \right) \, \mathrm d y}.
$$
Here $f$ is a smooth function such that $f(0) = \nabla f(0) = 0$ and ${\rm Hess} f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Is there a standard result asserting that the covariance matrix of $\rho$ is bounded from above, using the usual order on positive semidefinite matrices, by the identity matrix, i.e. that the presence of the function $f$ can only reduce the covariance compared to the case where $f = 0$? I have a proof for this in dimension one (see below), but I am interested in a proof for the **multidimensional case**.

A natural way of proceeding would be to find a bound on
$$
    \int_{\mathbb R^n} xx^T \, \rho(x) \, \mathrm d x,
$$
which is an upper bound for the covariance matrix.
This is the approach I take below, in dimension $n = 1$.

**Proof in the case $n = 1$.**
First note that
$$
\mathrm{Cov} (\rho) = \mathbb E_{X \sim \rho}(X^2) - |\mathbb E_{X \sim \rho}(X)|^2 \leq \mathbb E_{X \sim \rho}(X^2).
$$
Since
$$
    \mathbb E_{X \sim \rho} (X^2) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb P_{X \sim  \rho} (X^2 \geq y) \, \mathrm d y,
$$
it is sufficient to show $\mathbb P_{X \sim \rho} (X^2 \geq y) \leq \mathbb P_{X \sim g} (X^2 \geq y)$ for all $y \geq 0$,
where $g$ denotes the density of the standard normal distribution.
Showing this is equivalent, in view of the fact that the function $r \mapsto \frac{r}{1-r}$ is increasing for $y \in [0, 1]$, to proving the following:
$$
    \forall y > 0, \qquad
    \frac{\mathbb P_{X \sim \rho} (X^2 \geq y)}{\mathbb P_{X \sim \rho} (X^2 \leq y)} \leq \frac{\mathbb P_{X \sim g} (X^2 \geq y)}{\mathbb P_{X \sim g} (X^2 \leq y)}.
$$
But this is obvious because,
introducing the function $u(y) =  \exp \left( - f\left(y\right) \right) + \exp \left( - f\left(-y\right) \right)$,
which is positive and nonincreasing over $[0, \infty)$,
we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathbb P_{X \sim \rho} (X^2 \geq y)}{\mathbb P_{X \sim \rho} (X^2 \leq y)}
    &= \frac{\int_{y}^{\infty} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2}{2} \right)  u(x) \mathrm d x}
    {\int_{0}^{y} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2}{2} \right)  u(x) \mathrm d x}
    \leq
    \left( \frac{\max_{\{x^2 \geq y\}} u(x)}
    {\min_{\{x^2 \leq y\}} u(x)} \right)
    \frac{\int_{\{x^2 \geq y\}} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \mathrm d x}
    {\int_{\{x^2 \leq y\} } \exp \left( - \frac{x^2}{2} \right) \mathrm d x},
\end{align*}
and, since $f$ is smooth, the minimum and the maximum coincide.

**Ideas for the multi-dimensional case**. In the multi-dimensional case,
the approach above can be applied,
by passing to radial coordinates,
to obtain a bound of the form
$$
\mathrm{Trace}(\mathrm{Cov} (\rho)) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |x|^2 \, \rho(x) \, \mathrm d x \leq n,
$$
where $n$ is the dimension.
However, this gives only that
$$
    \mathrm{Cov} (\rho) \leq n I,
$$
i.e. there is an undesired factor $n$ on the right-hand side.
Here $I$ is the identity matrix

**Note**. In Bayesian terms, the function $e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$ can be viewed as a prior distribution,
the function $e^{-f}$ as the likelihood and $\rho$ as the posterior distribution.
The question can then be formulated as follows, approximately: is the posterior covariance bounded from above by the prior covariance given that the log-likelihood is convex.

Comment: "the presence of the function f can only reduce the covariance ". I must be missing something. Let $g(x)$ be the standard gaussian, and take $f(x)=x^2/4$. Then $\rho(x)\propto e^{-x^2/4}$, i.e., a variance of $2$.

Comment: Ah, wrong sign in the exponential, thanks! :)

Comment: 'that the covariance matrix of ρ is bounded from above by the identity matrix (in general dimension)'  -  bounded in which sense? what is the order? Also, what does your trace inequality mean? The left hand site is a number, on the right a matrix.

Comment: Sorry, these were typos. The inequality is in the sense of positive semidefinite matrices. –

Comment: Is it $\operatorname{Hess} f(x) \geq 0$ or $\operatorname{Hess} f(0) \geq 0$? Bounding smooth function only at origin cannot be sufficient.

Comment: The first one. Thanks for spotting this typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this follows from the Poincare inequality. See for example Theorem 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1510.pdf

For a $\rho$-convex function $V$, let $\mu$ be the distribution $\frac{1}{Z}e^{-V}$. For all smooth function $f$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int \bigg(f - \int f d\mu\bigg)^2 d\mu \leq \frac{1}{\rho} \int |\nabla f|^2 d\mu . 
\end{equation}

Take $f$ to be a linear function and $\rho = 1$ would give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Even if the author is apparently happy, could anyone elaborate a little more why that implies the answer? Taking $X\sim\mu$ and $f$ linear as suggested yields $\operatorname{Var}(X)\le\frac{1}{\rho}\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$. But for that insight Poincaré inequality is a bit overloaded.

Comment: @Tobsn In the case $f$ is linear, the right hand side is a constant.

Comment: Ah, true. Stupid me. But still, how do we get the covariance relation?

Comment: @Tobsn Let's say $f = c \cdot x$. Then we will get $c^T \text{Cov} c \leq 1$ for any $c$.

Comment: Sure, got it. Thank you!